# creating repetitive lines of texts/variable that calls values from a data frame

Tags: r, arrays, text, repeat

I need to create a text file whose content is a repetitive lines of texts that calls some contents/values coming from a dataframe. Here's to illustrate:

Suppose I have this dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data_frame(col1 = runif(5, 1, 5),
           col2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(5, 3))

#col1 col2 
#<dbl> <chr>
#1  3.72 NmV  
#2  2.43 HqH  
#3  4.46 xfy  
#4  4.97 dgV  
#5  3.11 wS9
```

I'd like to make a `.txt` file  that would look like this:

```
#Group 1
first_line = 3.72
second_line = NmV

#Group 2
first_line = 2.43
second_line = HqH

.
.
.

#Group 5
first_line = 3.11
second_line = wS9
```

Then I would like to write a text file that prints those repeating lines. I'm thinking of doing a for-loop or do it using `purrr`'s `map()` function but I figured working with texts is an entirely different ball game! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a create a single string by `paste`ing and then use `cat`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%
          mutate(rn = str_c('Group ', row_number())) %>% 
          pmap_chr(~ str_c(..3,  "\n", 'first_line = ', round(..1, 2), 
           '\n', 'second_line = ', ..2)) %>% 
         str_c(collapse="\n\n")
cat(out, file = 'filenew.txt')
```

Comment: Cool! That's exactly what I was expecting to get. I have a follow-up question. does the `..3` and `..2` indicates the column number? My actual data have more than 3 columns that's why I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @mand3rd  yes, it indicates the column values in the same order